# Как подсветить квадрат из группы?

Tags: javascript, svg

Имеется навигация которая имеет ссылку в виде `href="здесь id группы"` и так же имеются `<g>` внутри которых лежат два `rect` .

Верхний `rect` видно так как его стили записаны в теге, а нижний нет так как он стилизован в `css` и имеет `fill: transparent;`

**Как сделать что бы при прохождении курсора над ссылкой подсветить нужный прозрачный `rect` другими словами подменить на `fill: yellow;`?**

Мой код:

```js
let nav = document.querySelectorAll("a");
let rect = document.querySelectorAll("rect");
let g = document.querySelectorAll("g");

console.log(g)

for (var i = 0; i < nav.length; i++) {
  nav[i].mousemove = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    let event = e.target;

    console.log(event)
  }
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

g rect:nth-child(2) {
  fill: yellow;
  opacity: 0;
}

a {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px;
}

.svg {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#r1">section a</a>
<a href="#r2">section b</a>
<a href="#r3">section c</a>
<a href="#r4">section d</a>


<div class="svg">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 600 460">
    <g  id="r1">
       <rect x="100" y="100" width="50" height="30" fill="#00f" />
       <rect x="100" y="100" width="50" height="30" />
    </g>
    <g id="r2">
      <rect x="200" y="200" width="30" height="20" fill="#ccc" />
      <rect x="200" y="200" width="30" height="20" />
    </g>
    <g id="r3">
      <rect x="300" y="300" width="40" height="50" fill="#f00" />
      <rect x="300" y="300" width="40" height="50" />
    </g>
    <g id="r4">
      <rect x="400" y="400" width="40" height="40" fill="#0ff" />
      <rect x="400" y="400" width="40" height="40" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Если `var` заменить на `let`, переменная `i` для каждого якоря при mousemove будет своя. Останется по парам дать классы якорям и прямоугольникам, достать нужный элемент по индексу `i` )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
let nav = document.querySelectorAll("a");

for (let i = 0; i < nav.length; i++) {
  nav[i].addEventListener('mouseenter', function() {
    toggleRect(i, 1);
  });
  nav[i].addEventListener('mouseleave', function() {
    toggleRect(i, 0);
  });
}

function toggleRect(i, opacity) {
  let rect = document.querySelectorAll('div.svg g rect:nth-child(2)')[i];
  // let rect = document.querySelectorAll('div.svg g')[i].children[1];
  // let rect = document.getElementById('r' + (i + 1)).children[1];
  rect.style.opacity = opacity;
}
```

```css
g rect:nth-child(2) {
  fill: yellow;
  opacity: 0;
}

a {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
  margin: 6px;
}

.svg {
  width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#a">section a</a>
<a href="#b">section b</a>
<a href="#c">section c</a>
<a href="#c">section d</a>

<div class="svg">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 600 460">
    <g  id="r1">
       <rect x="10" y="0" width="10" height="10" fill="#00f" />
       <rect x="10" y="0" width="10" height="10" />
    </g>
    <g id="r2">
      <rect x="50" y="10" width="20" height="20" fill="#ccc" />
      <rect x="50" y="10" width="20" height="20" />
    </g>
    <g id="r3">
      <rect x="90" y="20" width="30" height="30" fill="#f00" />
      <rect x="90" y="20" width="30" height="30" />
    </g>
    <g id="r4">
      <rect x="130" y="40" width="40" height="40" fill="#0ff" />
      <rect x="130" y="40" width="40" height="40" />
    </g>
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: спасибо ..это было очень важно ...